# Hide partitions on RAID0 in GRUB2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, raid

I'm trying to hide two Windows versions from each other. I know how to do this on a single drive, however, it seems to be somewhat more difficult on a RAID0. More precisely, I don't know how to determine the exact order for the parttool.
This is an example of what I have so far in /etc/grub.d/40_custom:

```
menuentry "Work" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_hjcbchkb)'
    parttool (hd0,0) hidden-
    parttool (hd0,1) hidden+
    parttool (hd0,4) hidden-
    parttool (hd0,5) hidden-
    parttool (hd0,1) boot-
    parttool (hd0,0) boot+
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set B36431DD6432B247
    chainloader +1
}
```

The system boots up, but it seems that I dont' have the exact order for the partitions. I used blkid to determine the positions, but that doesn't seem to fit:

```
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
/dev/mapper/isw_hjcbchkb_Volume0p1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="A3D1DF14DCFA2DD3" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/mapper/isw_hjcbchkb_Volume0p2: LABEL="VM" UUID="3A2A29B22339B46C" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/mapper/isw_hjcbchkb_Volume0p5: LABEL="Work" UUID="B36431DD6432B247" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/mapper/isw_hjcbchkb_Volume0p6: LABEL="Other" UUID="C6C7A02AC8FCE722" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/mapper/isw_hjcbchkb_Volume0p7: UUID="02e4c321-2f22-3d2d-b1a8-021d98844d07" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/isw_hjcbchkb_Volume0p8: UUID="1ddf36d2-648d-24ab-7db2-03f2d680a70d" TYPE="swap"
```

In the example "Work", I want to boot Work (with BCD on "System Reserved") and hide VM.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got this working. No translation of the partition numbering is needed at all - logical partitions starting at #5. Therefore, the correct entry looks like this:

```
menuentry "Work" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(/dev/mapper/isw_hjcbchkb)'
    parttool (hd0,1) hidden-
    parttool (hd0,2) hidden+
    parttool (hd0,5) hidden-
    parttool (hd0,6) hidden+
    parttool (hd0,6) boot-
    parttool (hd0,1) boot+
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set B36431DD6432B247
    chainloader +1
}
```